# Update code shown here is not updating the items

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What is wrong with my code?

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near '('.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
>   Incorrect syntax near 'UP'.

SQL server says missing something

```
UPDATE 
(
SELECT
  T.Br, U.Br   AS Br1 ,
  T.Dis, U.Dis AS Disc1   ,
  T.DeletedDate , U.DeletedDate    AS DeletedDate1      ,
  T.INSERT_TS, U.INSERT_TS   AS INSERT_TS1
  FROM dbo.Matrix T
  JOIN tlt_svs.Matrix_Update U   
  ON T.Key= U.Key)UP
SET 
UP.Br = UP.Br1 ,
UP.Dis = UP.Dis1  ,
UP.DeletedDate   = UP.DeletedDate1    ,
UP.INSERT_TS         =  UP.INSERT_TS1
```

Comment: What should an `UPDATE` on a derived table do?

Comment: How do you think SQL Server should know which table you are updating?  I don't know which table you are updating.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want an `UPDATE` with a join, i.e. update the values of `matrix` with the corresponding values of `matrix_update`?

```
UPDATE m
       SET m.br = mu.br,
           m.dis = mu.dis,
           m.deleteddate = mu.deleteddate,
           m.insert_ts = mu.insert_ts
       FROM dbo.matrix m
            INNER JOIN tlt_svs.matrix_update mu
                       ON mu.key = m.key;
```